# What is a 'hally'?

Tags: meaning

I am reading Hilary Mantel's book, and there's this word, 'hally' or 'hallies',
which I couldn't find in any dictionary.

Some help, please?

> There is no obvious reason for voices and visions. My temperature is near normal and my pain relief is the usual moderate regime. Later the **hallies**, as I think of them, become less threatening, but more childish and conspiratorial. I close my eyes and they begin to pack my belongings into a pillow case, whispering and grinning. One sharp-faced dwarfish **hally** pulls at my right arm, and I drive her off with an elbow in her eye.

Comment: Thank you for the lovely question.  It was a bit more of a challenge than most; because, you are absolutely correct, this is not a word; but, a naming pattern that took a bit of work to figure out what was being renamed.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is slang, but not popular slang.  From reading quotes from Hilary Mantel's book, I think she is shortening "Hallucination" into "hally".

In English, changing the ending vowel sound to the "ie" or "y" sound shows it to be "small" and "familiar" (and sometimes cute).  This is especially true for names.  For example, I am Edwin; but, when I was young my family called me "Eddie".  Kittens become "kitties" and pups (child dogs) become "puppies".  This alternative way of naming something is rarely used when the item it big, scary, or dangerous; but, is often used when the item is familiar, friendly, or small.

The word "hallucinations" has too many syllables for this transition to this kind of diminutive.  The general rule is to drop the syllables at the end till there are only two "hal-lie" seems to fit this pattern.  Another example is the shortening of "pa-ja-mas" to "jam-mies".  As you can see the rule seems to require two syllables, but it is sometimes arbitrary if the starting syllables or the ending syllables are dropped.

Sometimes this pattern is used for single syllable words, in which case the word is stretched to fit the required two syllables.  Some examples include "snack" to "snack-ie" or "bad" (describing a person) to "bad-die".

Since the text talks about illness, mental illness, and making the mental illness seem less threatening, I think the person is saying they have named their "hallucinations" as "hallies", which fits the cultural renaming rules for making names diminutive.  This would also explain why it is not in any dictionary, it is not a proper word, but a convention of making a proper word into something nicer, happier, or more friendly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and helpful answer! Yes, it is 'hallucination'. What else could it be?! Now it seems so obvious. Thanks.

Comment: @woodslim Well, I didn't stumble on Hallucination at first either.   But like all puzzles, after you have the solution, it seems so obious! :)

Comment: @woodslim I finally found a longer passage, containing the quote.  https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v32/n21/hilary-mantel/diary It is clear she's been talking about hallucinations before starting to call them "hallies"